# Automapper get source value from a Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map from an item in a dictionary.

```
class Dest
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

class Src
{
    public string src { get; set }
}

mapper.CreateMap<Src, Dest>()
    .ForMember(m => m.src, opt.MapFrom(s => s.dict.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Key.Equals("id"))));
```

The item in the dictionary definitely exists but the value is not being mapped.

Any obvious mistakes?

Comment: Shouldn't it be m.src (with a small s)?

Comment: @Minu you're correct but that's not the problem. I used intellisense in code and it's correct. I corrected the example.

Comment: I don't even understand how Compiles, SingleOrDefault will return a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` And not a string,

Answer (score 0):

Argh. So it turns out my Dest class also has a property called `src`. It seems mapper is doing my optional map and then also doing a default `src` to `src` map.

Comment: Maybe ignoring unmapped values will help also, try to add this at the beginning of your code: mapper.IgnoreUnmapped();
and then create your custom mapping.